# Encrypting with attr-encrypt gem but can't decrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, attr-encrypted

Using gem: https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted

Issue 1:

When I create the record and encrypt, I go to the console (via Heroku) and do:

```
model = Model.find(1)
model.attribute
```

Error: `OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError ()`

Issue 2:

I create the record, go to edit, the params show decrypted (not sure how if it won't work in console, but does)...

Once I recommit (git push heroku master) or restart heroku, the edit page gives me this error: `ActionView::Template::Error ()`

The error is at the line for the text_field attribute `publishable key`

My setup:

Schema:

```
    t.string "encrypted_publishable_key"
    t.string "encrypted_publishable_key_iv"
    t.string "encrypted_secret_key"
    t.string "encrypted_secret_key_iv"
    t.index ["encrypted_publishable_key_iv"], name: "index_stripe_apis_on_encrypted_publishable_key_iv", unique: true
    t.index ["encrypted_secret_key_iv"], name: "index_stripe_apis_on_encrypted_secret_key_iv", unique: true
```

Tried removing the index's but still errors persist.

Model:

```
key = Base64.encode64(SecureRandom.random_bytes(32))
attr_encrypted :publishable_key, key: Base64.decode64(key)
attr_encrypted :secret_key, key: Base64.decode64(key)
```

Also tried with:

```
key = Base64.encode64(SecureRandom.random_bytes(32))
iv = Base64.encode64(SecureRandom.random_bytes(12))
attr_encrypted :publishable_key, key: Base64.decode64(key), iv: Base64.decode64(iv)
attr_encrypted :secret_key, key: Base64.decode64(key), iv: Base64.decode64(iv)
```

Wihtout `key = Base64.encode64(SecureRandom.random_bytes(32))` I get the error "32 bytes required".

With the above, the attributes will save but on decryption, both in views and console, I get error:

`iv must be 12 bytes or longer`

What am I doing wrong that this will not work?

Comment: You generate random keys on each app boot. No wonder your records stop displaying after deploy

Comment: Great.   So I should use a stationary key that I set myself basically? And any ideas on why I can't decrypt? Does starting the console do anything?

Comment: A console is a separate app instance (which means new random keys)